# Stacking IF Statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to pull data from another sheet based on selections made from multiple dropdown boxes. For example... If column 1 text reads RAZA pull data, if column 1 reads Standard pull data. So on and so forth. What I have done so far is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet1!C2="Raza",QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZLFN3ix5FtRoOPIUfxFl1oPsobFFahKqod9tOLGDgcY","Playfield!$A$2:$f"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col1 = 'Raza'"),IF(Sheet1!C3="Standard",QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZLFN3ix5FtRoOPIUfxFl1oPsobFFahKqod9tOLGDgcY","Playfield!$A$2:$f"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col1 = 'Standard'"))))`

The first IF statement pulls data accordingly, the second one does not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the formula in the question use

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZLFN3ix5FtRoOPIUfxFl1oPsobFFahKqod9tOLGDgcY","Playfield!$A$2:$f"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col1 = '"&Sheet1!C2&"'")`

The above because the value on `Sheet1!C2` is used as the value to be compared with the values on `Col1`, `&` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This formula seems to extract the data accordingly, but how would I stack that formula to also include &Sheet1!C3&, and &Sheet1!C4&, and so on and so forth.
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZLFN3ix5FtRoOPIUfxFl1oPsobFFahKqod9tOLGDgcY","Playfield!$A$2:$f"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col1 = '"&Sheet1!C2&"'"),QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ZLFN3ix5FtRoOPIUfxFl1oPsobFFahKqod9tOLGDgcY","Playfield!$A$2:$f"),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 WHERE Col1 = '"&Sheet1!C3&"'")
This did not seem to work at all...

Comment: @RickBlevins you have to build an array using curly braces `={QUER(...);QUERY(...)}`

Comment: Thank you sooooo very much Ruben. You have helped me immensely this afternoon.